# Multiplicative function on matrix space such that $f(0) = 0$ and $ f(I_n)=1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I came across this exercise : let $f: M(n, \mathbb R) \to \mathbb R$ a multiplicative function that $f(0) = 0$ and $f(I_n)=1$, show that $A$ is invertible if and only if $f(A) \neq 0$.

If A is invertible then $1=f(I_n)=f(AA^{-1})=f(A)f(A^{-1})$, so $f(A) \neq 0$, but I struggle to  prove that $f(A)=0$ if $A$ is not invertible.

This is a generalization of the properties of the determinant, but I remember using  the fact that the determinant is an multilinear alternate form on the columns of the matrix to show that $det(A)=0$ if $A$ is not invertible, and $f$ is not supposed to have this property here.

Comment: @Arthur that function is not multiplicative though, take any invertible matrix $B \ne I$, we have $1=f(I)=f(BB^{-1} \ne f(B)f(B^{-1}) = 0$

Comment: @RichardJensen I missed "multiplicative" in the title. It isn't in the actual problem statement in the question body.

Comment: I see. Btw OP, there is an answer to be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1863655/multiplicative-functions-on-matrices)

Answer (score 1):

Since all matrices of the same rank are equivalent (i.e. if $A$ and $B$ have the same rank, then $B=PAQ$ for some invertible matrices $P$ and $Q$), the multiplicative property implies that if $f(A)=0$ for some $A$, then $f(B)=0$ for every matrix $B$ of the same rank as $A$.

Now let $L:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ be the cyclic shift  $L(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n-1},x_n)=(x_n,x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n-1})$. For any $r<n$, let $u=(1,\ldots,1,0,\ldots,0)$ be the vector with $r$ copies of $1$ followed by $n-r$ copies of zero and let
$$
A_k=\operatorname{diag}(L^ku)
$$
for each integer $k\ge0$. Then $f(A_0)f(A_1)\cdots f(A_{n-1})=f(A_0A_1\cdots A_{n-1})=f(0)=0$. Hence some $f(A_i)$ must be zero, i.e., $f$ maps some rank-$r$ matrix to zero. Consequently, $f$ maps all rank-$r$ matrices to zero.

Comment: @Arthur The OP assumes in the title that $f$ is multiplicative, i.e., $f(AB)=f(A)f(B)$.

Comment: Yeah, I saw it in the title right after commenting. I somehow just assumed that because there was a full problem statement in the body, the title had no additional information. It isn't supposed to, and when it does, it's usually because that's the only place there is a problem statement..

Comment: @user1551 Thank you. So the matrices $A_k$ have same images as $A$ under $f$ because they are obtained by conjugating $A$ with permutation matrices, is that correct ?

Comment: @KieranMcShane Not exactly. Yes,  the $A_i$s turn out to have the same images as $A_0$ because each $f(A_i)=0$ for all $i$. But this fact isn't needed in my answer. My argument goes like this: (1) we infer that $f(A_0)f(A_1)\cdots f(A_{n-1})=0$. (2) Thus $f(A_i)$ is zero for some $i$. (3) Thus $f(B)=0$ for all $B$s with the same rank as $A_i$, i.e. $f(B)=0$ whenever the rank of $B$ is $r$. Now, from (3), we can indeed infer that $f(A_i)=0$ for every $A_i$ (because each $A_i$ has the same rank as $A_0$), but this is irrelevant to the derivation of $(1)\Rightarrow(2)\Rightarrow(3)$.