# Construct a function on matrices where $f(C) \times f(C^{-1}) = 1$

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider $f : M_n \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$, where $M_n$ represents all invertible $n\times n$ matrices.

I want to find some $f$ satisfying $\forall C, f(C)\times f(C^{-1}) = 1$。

For example, determinant is a possible answer. I want to know are there other possible $f$? Even more, can we find a series of $f$ using some methods?

Comment: any rational scalar multiple of the determinant will also be an answer

Comment: $f=1$ for all matrices also works

Comment: Must $f$ have rational values? Or even real ones are ok?  Are $C$'s elements real, rational...?

Answer (score 1):

Without any further restrictions on $f$, the most general form of this function is the following.

For each matrix $A$ such that $A^{-1}=A$ set $f(A)=1$ or $-1$. All other invertible matrices can be broken into pairs $\{A,A^{-1}\}$. For each such pair, set $f(A)$ be any nonzero rational number, and set $f(A^{-1})=f(A)^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answering! If I still wants $f(AB) = f(A)f(B)$, What further restrictions we need for $f$ ?

Comment: @rddccd This question is more complicated, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1863655/multiplicative-functions-on-matrices

Comment: Thanks! This helps a lot.